# New form opens in the background

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am working on a multi form application, with about 6 forms. Everything runs normal when I want to open another form and close the current one. I just run this code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MetroLoader
{
    public partial class updater : MetroForm
    {
        int val = 0;
        bool dir = true;
        bool upd = false;

        public updater()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Start();
            CheckUpdate();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (val == 0)
                dir = true;
            if (val == 100)
                dir = false;
            if (dir == true)
            {
                metroProgressSpinner1.Value = val;
                val = val + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                metroProgressSpinner1.Value = val;
                val = val - 1;
            }
        }

        private void CheckUpdate()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.DataSource = "x.database.windows.net";
                builder.UserID = "x";
                builder.Password = "x";
                builder.InitialCatalog = "Sirius Accounts Database";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE lastver='1.3'");
                    String sql = sb.ToString();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            upd = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            upd = true;
                            this.Text = "Update available!";
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (upd == true)
                {
                    metroProgressSpinner1.Visible = false;
                    timer1.Stop();
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    metroButton1.Visible = true;
                    label1.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    this.Hide();
                    var form1 = new Form1();
                    form1.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                    form1.Show();
                }
            }
        }

        private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object link = "www.google.ro";
            try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.DataSource = "x.database.windows.net";
                builder.UserID = "x";
                builder.Password = "x";
                builder.InitialCatalog = "Sirius Accounts Database";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE this='True'");
                    String sql = sb.ToString();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            link = reader["downLink"];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Convert.ToString(link));
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and everything is perfect. But today, I decided to change my main form, the one that starts when I first run the program, and I went in program.cs and changed it to the new one. Perfect! But now, if I try to close this new main form, and open ANY other form, they just open behind this one. I was like, fine, I will just close the other one, but if I try to close any of the forms, the whole application exits. It seems like the other forms depend on the main one somehow.

Comment: "But now, if I try to close this new main form, and open ANY other form.." here are you trying to hide it (the way you have shown in sample code) or actually closing it?

Comment: You may try just hiding the main form, while you show other forms, instead of closing it. As you saw then the main form is closed the application exits. Try this.Hide().

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am trying to close it. But this sample code I saw on the internet, works for other forms. Sorry for not mentioning, but even if I try to just hide it, nothing happens. It's odd. When I arrive home, I will post the complete code of the form. Thanks